# No puedo compilar Visual Studio 2017

Tags: .net, visual-studio, mvc, visual-studio-2017

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto con .NET y MVC y no puedo compilar mi solución por cada proyecto me sale este error:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Roslyn\Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets(84,5): error MSB6006: "csc.exe" salió con el código -532462766.

Yo estaba trabajando este proyecto en VS 2015 y me cambiaron de máquina (PC), instalé el VS 2017 Community y empezó a tirar ese error. Intente varias cosas como borrar `bin` y `obj`, ejecutar como administrador, etc y nada funcionó.

Comment: [mira esto](https://support.microsoft.com/es-es/help/832597/fix-you-may-receive-an-application-error-in-vbc-exe-or-csc-exe-when-yo)

Comment: ¿Podrías decirnos qué tipo de proyecto es el que estabas trabajando? ¿Qué framework estabas usando?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Necesitas instalar el paquete de Nuget `Microsoft.Net.Compilers` en tu proyecto.

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Net.Compilers -Version 2.3.2
```

En caso no te salga, revisa la fecha de creación de tu proyecto en referencia al paquete, por ejemplo, si lo instalaste antes del 5/17/2016, te corresponde esta versión:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Net.Compilers -Version 1.2.1
```

Referencia del paquete: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Compilers/

Comment: Ya lo intente también y no hubo caso

Comment: ¿Has instalado .net core?

Comment: respuesta actualizada

Comment: Lo probé con y sin .net core y tampoco hubo forma. Lo que recién veo es que pusiste la version 2.3.2 y yo trate con la v1.2.1 y v2.2.0 ahora pruebo con esa

Comment: dale! esto lo solucionamos de alguna manera con todo el power 2.0!! Saludos :D

Comment: Intente con todas las versiones una por una y no funciono realmente

Comment: revisa en tu código, mira si tienes puntos y comas correctamente, verifica que tengas las llaves de apertura y cierre "{ }" exactamente en el lugar donde deben.

Comment: Revise y no habia ningun faltante realmente no le encontre solucion tuve que reiniciar windows de fabrica y ahi funciono alguno archivo o programa debia esta interfieriendo. Muchas gracias igual

Comment: Vale, de nada bro :D